# Dictionary with Enum value type - calling the indexer for a key not in the dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, enums

I just ran into a slight problem. I have

`IDictionary<Something,MyEnum> map;`

I thought to write a method:

```
MyEnum GetMapping(Something x);
```

Used a bit like:

```
MyEnum e = GetMapping(x)
if(e!=null){...}
```

But of course the problem is since `MyEnum` is a standard `Enum` based on `int`, `GetMapping` *cannot* return null. Having to add a separate `DoesMappingExist` method seems messy, is there a neat way to address this?

And, what would `map[AnObjectNotInTheMap]` actually return - simply `Default(MyEnum)` i.e. `0`?

Comment: You can use nullables: `MyEnum? GetMapping(...)`

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this bit of C# functionality, it looks ideal

Comment: you can add the first value named ``null`` or ``no selection``, default would be first value of enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use value-types as nullables using `Nullable<T>`, a shorthand for this is `T?`.

So, your code should be something like this:

```
MyEnum? GetMapping(Something x)
{
    if (...) return MyEnum.SomeValue;
    if (...) return MyEnum.OtherValue;

    return null;
}
```

Then, use it like this:

```
MyEnum? e = GetMapping(x);
if(e.HasValue)
{
    var mapped = e.Value;
    ...
}
```

Comment: So I should use `e.HasValue` not `e != null`?

Comment: @Mr.Boy: You can use both, but `HasValue` is the recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Just go with nullable enum:

`IDictionary<Something,MyEnum?> map;`

And your method also changes as:

`MyEnum? GetMapping(Something x);`

Answer (score 0):

The default value of Enum is 0. So you don't assign 0 to any member of MyEnum, 0 can indicate a no-mapping. This should be the easiest implementation unless 0 has to be allocated in MyEnum.